# Pass event info to child component as props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to pass the height of the parent component to one of its children. I eventually managed to do so with saving `event.nativeEvent.layout.height` in the **state** of the parent and passing that as a prop to the child (here: `mySubComponent2`).

However, since the height of the parent will not change after rendering, I believe the height should rather be in **props**. How can I pass `myHeight` to `MySubComponent2` as a prop?
Here's what I tried and what doesn't work:

```js
render: function() {
  return (
    <View onLayout={(event) => {
      var myHeight = event.nativeEvent.layout.height;
    }}>
      <MySubComponent1 />
      <MySubComponent2 parentHeight={this.myHeight} />
    </View>
  );
},
```

What I actually want to do is have two flexDirection: 'column' within a flexDirection: 'row' View and let the two child-components have the same length, e.g. something like on the following picture:

[image: two_columnDirection_components_in_rowDirection_comp]

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to achieve what you're looking for (tested):

```
getInitialState() {
  return {
    height:0
  }
},

measure() {
  this.refs.mycomponent.measure((a, b, width, height) => {
    this.setState({ height })
   })
},

<View ref="mycomponent" style={{ height: 300 }} onLayout={ () => this.measure() }>
  <MySubComponent2 parentHeight={this.state.height} />
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nader, but as I wrote above I managed to solve this problem by using the state myself (I solved it very similar to you, without the need to use `refs` for that). What I am looking for here is a solution without reverting to the state.

Comment: Not sure it will rerender unless it is somehow attached to the state.

Comment: I think Nader is right. The hight information is something not inherent in the inter state of the react app. It get's passed in via the bridge and need to be represented as state somehow. However, if you want to keep this particular component state free you can always pass in a handler function and keep track of the height in some parent component. Then of course you have to pass it in as a prop again, which is kind of weired in this case.

Comment: @dvine multimedia I see. But in the case I keep the height in the state, it leads me to another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114736/passing-onlayout-event-nativeevent-layout-height-from-parent-to-child-component