# Passing onLayout event.nativeEvent.layout.height from parent to child component causes infinitely growing height value

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[See the code in action on rnplay.org](https://rnplay.org/apps/-5DJTQ) - if you make changes to the code, reload the browser window and hit "Tap to Play" again. I made some notes there inside the components to explain the problem.

Here my written explanation:

My basic problem: I want to make **two sibling components the same height**. The content of one sibling (here: SubComponent1) is dynamically fetched from the database and thus defines the height of the parent. I want it to also define the height of SubComponent 2. See image:

[image: before_after]

I tried to implement that by sending the height of the parent to the static child (SubComponent 2) via props. Here's the `render` part in the parent component:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.parentContainer} onLayout={this._onLayoutEvent}>
      <Text>Parent Component </Text>
      <SubComponent1 />
      <SubComponent2 parentHeight={this.state.parentHeight} />
    </View>
  );
},

_onLayoutEvent: function(event) {
  this.setState({parentHeight: event.nativeEvent.layout.height});
}
```

And here I add it to the child:

```
<View style={[styles.subComponent2View, {height: this.props.parentHeight}]}>
```

However, this does not work! The SubComponent's height increases in an infinite loop.. see image: [image: infinite_growth]

Surprisingly dividing by `1.01` makes it work! That is, changing the above line in the child to

```
<View style={[styles.subComponent2View, {height: this.props.parentHeight / 1.01}]}>
```

does not cause growing height and I get the following where you can barely see the height difference of `0.01`. However dividing by `1.001` again causes the infinite loop... I really can't explain why! Here the result when diving by `1.01`: [image: dividing Parent Height by 1.01]

Can someone explain that strange behavior?

Are there alternative solutions to my problem? 
- Setting `alignSelf: 'stretch'` on SubComponent2 also does not work.
- Would it perhaps help to send the height from the one sibling to the other (i.e. from SubComponent 1 to SubComponent2)? If so, I probably need to implement something using the `Flux` pattern, right?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to define the height explicitly at all in the first place.  With flexbox, it should be trivial to achieve what you're looking for.  Just assign `flex: 1` to both child component containers as well as on the parent, while the parent will have the addition of a `flex-direction: 'row'`.

To illustrate, here's a web version of what I mean.  Instead of `display: flex` you use `flex: 1` but the point is the same:  https://jsfiddle.net/2rc4b2qy/

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't help. I also thought it's a trivial issue for flexbox but it somehow isn't in react native. I exactly tried what you said but it doesn't work.. I added a link to my code to my question. Here's the link again https://rnplay.org/apps/03qVtw

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

onLayout - you put new data by setState which cause new render() and here problem

New render cause new onLayout!!! =( sad, very sad

Had a big problem with it, so can use just e.g. this.dynamicSize = ...

instead setState({dynamicSize: ...}) but need some forceUpdate() for example to re-render but again - look to prevent loop

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html - here you try different methods to prevent the loop but update immediately